Is the Hadamard Product of two laplacian operators allowed to get some kind of biharmonic operator?
I'm currently working on my masters thesis in computer science and from this point I'm not that into this subject. Right know I try to understand the steps the authors of this paper did to get the matrix they called ELoG filter. This is for interpolating some type of filters for a Convolutional Neural Network. They approximated the laplacian operator on two different ways. With these two approximations they did a convolution and normalized it afterwards. I searched through the whole web for a few days but couldn't find anything. So the two matrices are:
Laplacian Approximation 1:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -4 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
Laplacian Approximation 2:
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
2 & -4 & 2 \\
-1 & 2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
After Convolution and Normalization the ELoG matrix should be the result.
ELoG matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 8 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
I don't know how a convolution should result to this matrix. The only way I would think of to get there is, to use the Hadamard Product. 
So my question is, is it allowed in mathematical manner to build the hadamard product without harming any law of linear operators and linear combinations or anything?
On page four you can find the chapter about this: Link to the paper
